# Different results for Welch Two Sample T-Test between Python and R

Tags: python, r, statistics, data-analysis

I'm using exactly same data set

In Python, data type of Status=Category, Age=int64

In R, data type of Status=Factor.

What did I do wrongly?

**Python**

```
sp.stats.ttest_ind(df['age'], df['status'], equal_var=False)
Ttest_indResult(statistic=152.89506180745045, pvalue=0.0)
```

**R**

```
t.test(age ~ status, data = data)
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  age by status
t = -0.30302, df = 310.18, p-value = 0.7621
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:

 -1.491510  1.093425
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       45.41860        45.61765
```

Reply to Deschan. What I get in Python

```
{'e_code': 0      45631
 1      45632
 2      45633
 3      45634
 4      45635
        ...  
 681    46267
 682    46290
 683    46312
 684    46336
 685    46359
 Name: e_code, Length: 686, dtype: int64,
 'status': 0      0
 1      0
 2      0
 3      0
 4      0
       ..
 681    1
 682    1
 683    1
 684    1
 685    1
 Name: status, Length: 686, dtype: category
 Categories (2, int64): [0, 1],
 681    52
 682    37
 683    51
 684    38
 685    55
 Name: age, Length: 686, dtype: int64}
```

What I got in R.

```
structure(list(age = c(51, 47, 46, 50, 57, 57, 57, 52, 42, 38, 
48, 55, 51, 41, 54, 47, 48, 44, 44, 45), status = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Hope this clarify !

**Solved! Deschan was correct. My python coding was wrong. The approach is different from R**

```
sp.stats.ttest_ind(df.query('status==0')['age'], df.query('status==1')['age'], equal_var=False)
```

Comment: Can you share your data or at least create a small example with e.g. the first 20 rows using `dput(df[1:20, c('age', 'status')])`.

Comment: Apparently there‘s something going on, because the results kind of indicate the opposite. Your python code suggest a t value of 152, which is incredibly/unrealistically large, so my guess is that there‘s something wrong rather with your python code.

Comment: @deschen I tried, is it something that you wanted to see?

Comment: Thanks. But the first 20 rows only contain people with status = 0. please try the following: `library(tidyverse); data %>% group_by(status) %>% slice_head(n=10) %>% ungroup() %>% select(age, status) %>% dput()`.